# Animation looping while holding button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, scripting

I have got problem when i shoot.I press LMB and it plays animation once.I need to play it 30 times (or magazine capacity)

I font know how to set make it repeat every 0.15 seconds.

Comment: This is not the correct format for stackoverflow questions. Don’t ask for help without showing what you have tried first. Either way, you are probably looking for coroutines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.